# Use jquery to get value of field with dynamically generated name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with field names that are generated dynamically by server side code. 
I am attempting to allow JQuery to manipulate the value of these fields, but am running into trouble.

The generated fields are paired using a unique ID number Example:

A radio button named option_3030
Will have a amount_3030 field

The number of dynamically created fields is also an unknown (there might be one or ten input pairs -- all named  option_xxxx and amount_xxxx.

What I'm trying to do is use jquery to set the value of the 3030_amount field when the 3030_option is checked (or unchecked). The problem is, I don't know ahead of time what the actual id number will be.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

David

Comment: each radio has its own value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the id attribute and take the number from it:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function()
{
    var id = this.id.split(/_/)[1];
    var amount = $('input[name=amount_' + id + ']');
    amount.val(123);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use classes:

```
<input type="radio" id="3030_Option" class="option" />
<input type="text" id="3030_amount" class="amount" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.option').click(function() {
         $(this).next('.amount').val('new value goes here')
    })
})
</script>
```

By the way starting html ids with numbers is technically [not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Comment: Sure but I bet OP have more than one (option, amount) pair :) You have to use $(this).next('.amount')

Comment: @vava: I bet you're right. However I answer questions as they stand, and this one doesn't mention multiple elements.

Comment: I've adjusted my question for clarity. I have also adjusted my code to conform to proper naming convention. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your event with a class, and then parse the id of the clicked element to get the numerical identifier to use for the text field.

```
<input type="radio" id="3030_Option" class="option" />
<input type="text" id="3030_amount" class="amount" />
<input type="radio" id="3031_Option" class="option" />
<input type="text" id="3031_amount" class="amount" />


$('.option').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = id.substring(0, id.indexOf('_'));
    $('#' + num + '_amount').val('value');
});
```

As pointed out by others, numerals are not valid as the initial character of an id. It would be better to suffix them. In which case the code needs modifying slightly.

```
<input type="radio" id="Option_3030" class="option" />
<input type="text" id="amount_3030" class="amount" />
<input type="radio" id="Option_3031" class="option" />
<input type="text" id="amount_3031" class="amount" />

$('.option').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = id.substring(id.indexOf('_') + 1, id.length);
    $('#amount_' + num).val('value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mhh i think you could try to register the javascipt function while generating the code. I have done somthing similar with a gridview.

```
generatedControl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "jqueryFunction(" generatedId ")" );
```